# Can iDeal process international credit cards, for international payments?

Tags: payments

Can iDeal process international credit cards, for international payments ?

I'm not talking about trasferring money from bank accounts, but to use it as safe payment gateway for international credit cards all over world.

I need a good solution for my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading [their website](http://www.ideal.nl/banken/?lang=eng-GB) I would say they do not offer credit card payments of any kind as they seem to only offer bank-to-bank money transfers.